# Cant change the background image with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, background-image

I'm just trying to change my background image on my website. I can change the background color but not the image. This is my first timeusing php so I don't know if I should know something there. Just been using HTML/CSS/JS. Appreciate the help!

style.css

```
body{
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-image: url("/img/indexbackground.png");
}
```

index.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Quickbuy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
```

Comment: _"This is my first timeusing php"_ - I don't see how PHP is relevant here at all though? Even if the file ends with .php, any HTML/JS/CSS on the page will still work the same. I'm assuming that the posted CSS is in `style.css`?

Comment: Thats right its in style.css and path to the image it right im 99% sure. Im sorry im fresh to php so i have no idea, usually works when I wasn't using php that's all haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't put your CSS inside of a style tag.

You also didn't include `</html>`. That doesn't affect this issue, however it may cause issues with more complex webpages and older browsers.

Here is the updated code, in a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quickbuy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      background-image: url("/img/indexbackground.png");
      background-color: #22d; /*Background color is being used to replace background image, remove it in your code.*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

</html>
```

CSS can't just be like this

```
element {
  color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

It must be in a style tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    element {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry that i wasnt more clear. The css code is in a css file "style.css" and i've just like them together. And the reason that i dont have an </head> is bec its included in a php file. As i said i can change the color in my css file and if i change it in my html code with style tags but not with an image.

Comment: So the image isn't working? Either there is a server (PHP) error or the image URL is invalid. Try just running the code in a folder off of a file:// url and try it. Also including your PHP code might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
         background-image: url("/img/indexbackground.png");
    }

</style>
```

Otherwise there may be some syntax problems in your link.
And don't forget to save your code after you changed it.